# search order by title youtube api

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

how do I order by title in php in the youtube api? In the documentation in the search.list it says order is an optional parameter. How do I order what I print by title or date?
 try {

```
// Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
// query term.
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
));

$videos = '';
$channels = '';
$playlists = '';
// Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
// matching videos, channels, and playlists.
foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
  switch ($searchResult['id']['snippet']) {
    case 'youtube#video':
      $videos .= sprintf('<li>title=%s link = http://youtube.com/watch?v=%s/ channelid = %s</li><br> ',
          $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['videoId'], $searchResult['snippet']['channelTitle']);
      break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the order parameter to sort by title, date, rating, relevance, videoCount, and viewCount. Take a look at the documentation for order: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

This code sorts by title

```
// Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
// query term.
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
  'order' => 'title'
));
```

This code sorts by date

```
// Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
// query term.
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
  'order' => 'date'
));
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: whenever i do  'order' => 'viewCount' it doesn't return anything

Comment: viewCount is only for channels. It sorts channels from most uploaded videos to least uploaded videos.